# How can I represent a byte array that contains non-visible ASCII for doctest?

Tags: python-3.x, doctest

I have the following Python code:

```
def example(byte_array):
    """
    Return the byte array.
    >>> example(b'\x01')
    b'\x01'
    """
    return byte_array
```

When this code is executed with python3, the doctest fails. Below is the output:

```
**********************************************************************
File "example.py", line 74, in __main__.example
Failed example:
    example(b'')
Expected:
    b''
Got:
    b'\x01'
```

The Expected result is wrong. How can I write this such that the test passes? Must I do something convoluted like `example(b\'x01') is b'\x01'` matching `True`, or is there a better solution?

Note that when `example(b'\0x2d')` is used instead, the test passes correctly, presumably because the character 0x2d is the dash ("-"), and prints to the terminal visibly.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the backslash in  the string.

```
"""
 ...
b'\\x01'
 ...
"""
```

Comment: *winces* I swear I tried that. Thanks. Is there a way to avoid having to escape the backslash for non-printable characters, but not for printable characters?

Answer (score 0):

Whereas the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45898737/11163122) of escaping the backslash works, `flake8` (version `3.8.4`) will complain:

```
D301 Use r""" if any backslashes in a docstring
```

A better method is to make the docstring be a raw string literal with  a leading `r`:

- No need for the escaping backslash in the expected output
- `flake8` no longer raises an error either

```py
def example(byte_array):
    r"""
    Return the byte array.

    >>> example(b'\x01')
    b'\x01'
    """
    return byte_array
```